# mdx: Merging rows into single row using mdx

Tags: mdx

[image]

From the attached screenshot, how can we group the 5 rows into a single row with out having the second column using mdx query?

Expected single row with GD, FR, PR, NC & NT Value with 4

```
WITH
MEMBER Gd as iif([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].currentmember is  [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].   
[Label].&[GD],
[Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count], null)
MEMBER fr as iif([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].currentmember is  [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency]. 
[Label].&[FR],
[Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count], null)
MEMBER pr as iif([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].currentmember is  [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].
[Label].&[PR],
[Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count], null)
MEMBER nt as iif([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].currentmember is  [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].
[Label].&[NT],
[Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count], null)
MEMBER nc as iif([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].currentmember is  [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].
[Label].&[NC],
[Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count], null)


select {Gd, fr, pr, nt, nc} on 0,
([DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Metric Id].[Metric Id],[DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].  
[Label])      
on  1
from [StrategyCompanionDWCube]
```

Comment: Hi, please re-upload your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not simply say

```
select [DimMetricNumeratorFrequency].[Label].[Label]
       on 0,
       { [Measures].[Patient Key Distinct Count] }    
       on  1
from [StrategyCompanionDWCube]
```

MDX does not require the measures to be on columns.

Comment: Hi FranK, Thanks a lot. I agree with you but i am new with MDX that is the reason i could not able to achive my requirements. Could you please suggest any website which explains with exmples OR Videos on MDX.

Comment: @mohan111 I do not know good websites for a goof introduction into MDX. I learnt MDX the old way from paper books. There are not that many, so that an Amazon search on "MDX Introduction" should list most of them.